# Eclipse and Android Tutorial PubSub Errors

Tags: rosjava, eclipse, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been battling through installing a development environment to use rosjava to communicate with a robot (pc) from an android device.  I am relatively new to ROS and Android programming.

I have managed to finally get pubsub installed on my phone and functioning (from the command line), thanks to a lot of tidbits from everyone on Ros answers.

I now seem to be having issues getting the project to run from an eclipse environment.  I created a new Android Project and created from existing source, pointing to android_tutorial_pubsub.

This left me with some unresolved errors.

My first attempt to fix this I added all the jars I could from android_gingerbread and rosjava until the errors were gone.  I was then able to get the app on my phone but it would fail every time I tried to run it.  I did notice that under properties->android the android_gingerbread reference had a big red X next to it.

My next attempt was remove all the library references and to create a new android project from existing source and point to android_gingerbread to bring it into eclipse.  This removed all the errors and resulted in a green check mark beside the android_gingerbread reference.

But now when I try to compile I simply get a java heap error, crashing eclipse.  I've increased the size of the heap but it just keeps happening.

Is importing android_gingerbread as an Android project not the right way to import it into eclipse?  Is there another environment that I can use to modify the pubsub code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31107/eclipse-and-android-tutorial-pubsub-errors/) by [Brainmuck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2106/brainmuck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brainmuck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2106/brainmuck/) on 2012-04-04**:
I pulled the new files and compiled the rosjava_core fine.  But the Android_core won't compile now.  It fails on UpdateProject.  It can't seem to find the command android in the folder to 'update project'  But if I call android from the directory it opens the SDK manager fine.  So the path is there.

**Comment by [Brainmuck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2106/brainmuck/) on 2012-04-04**:
Ok now parts of android_core compile, had to add -target 1 to the gradle build file to target android-10 based on my target list. I still get a java heap problem when trying to run in eclipse though.   android_honeycomb_mr2 won't compile do I need it for pubsub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There were some significant changes in the past couple days that left android_core broken. However, android_core and its documentation have been updated as of today. I suggest pulling and trying again.

http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html
http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/building.html

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0